# Generalization of the law of tangents for a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

The law of tangents is a statement about the relationship between the tangents of two angles of a triangle and the lengths of the opposing sides.

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be the lengths of the three sides of a triangle, and $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be the angles opposite those three respective sides. The law of tangents states that

$$\frac{\tan\frac12(\alpha-\beta)}{\tan\frac12(\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{a-b}{a+b}\tag{1}$$

The law of tangent can be used in any case where two sides and the included angle, or two angles and a side, are known.

Although Viète gave us the modern version of the law of tangents, it was Fincke who stated the law of tangents for the first time and also demonstrated its application by solving a triangle when two sides and the included angle are given (see [Wu - The Story of Mollweide and Some Trigonometric Identities](http://www.geocities.ws/galois_e/pdf/mollweide%20article.pdf))

A proof of the law of tangent is provided by Wikipedia (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents)).

**Generalization**. Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ be the sides of a cyclic convex quadrilateral. Let $\angle{DAB}=\alpha$ and  $\angle{ABC}=\beta$, then the following identity holds

$$\frac{\tan\frac12(\alpha-\beta)}{\tan\frac12(\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a+c)(b+d)}\tag{2}$$

**Proof**. Using the sum-to-product formulas we can rewrite the left-hand side of $(2)$ as follows

$$\frac{\tan\frac12(\alpha-\beta)}{\tan\frac12(\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\sin\frac12(\alpha-\beta)\cos\frac12(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos\frac12(\alpha-\beta)\sin\frac12(\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\sin{\alpha}-\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\alpha}+\sin{\beta}}.$$

The area of a cyclic quadrilateral can be expressed as $\Delta=\frac12(ad+bc)\sin{\alpha}$ (see $(12)$ at [Killing three birds with one stone](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/07/killing-three-birds-with-one-stone.html)) and similarly for the other angles. Then substituting, simplifying and factorizing we have

$$\begin{align*}\frac{\tan\frac12(\alpha-\beta)}{\tan\frac12(\alpha+\beta)}&=\frac{\frac{2\Delta}{ad+bc}-\frac{2\Delta}{ab+cd}}{\frac{2\Delta}{ad+bc}+\frac{2\Delta}{ab+cd}}=\frac{ab-ad+cd-bc}{ab+ad+cd+bc}=\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a+c)(b+d)}\end{align*}.$$

$\square$

The formula $(2)$ reduces to the law of tangent for a triangle when $c=0$.

A related result can be found at [A generalization of Mollweide's formula (rather Newton's)](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2022/01/generalization-of-mollweides-formulas.html).

Crossposted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419185/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-tangents).

**Question: Is this generalization known?**

**A historical correction**: Fincke was not the first to publish the law of tangents. It was actually Ibn Muadh who first described it in the 11th century. See the discussion at [HSMSE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15241/who-published-the-law-of-tangents-first/15256#15256).

Comment: I haven't seen yet such an identity but I am not a specialist of this kind of geometry. You should submit it to a journal like [Journal of Classical Geometry](https://jcgeometry.org/) or [Crux Mathematicorum](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/); there, the referees are likely to say whether this identity is known or not.

Comment: You can also varify your identity from here :https://groups.io/g/Quadri-and-Poly-Geometry     , in this group people may help you in varying your theorem as their research feild are related to quadrilateral and polygon.

Comment: Defining $\theta_a:=\angle ADB=\angle ACB$, you can write $a=2r\sin\theta_a$. Likewise, $b=2r\sin\theta_b$, $c=\cdots$, $d=\cdots$. Then, the expression on the right-hand side of your identity is rewritable, via sum- and difference-to-product identities, into tangents. Simple angle-chasing reduces the result to your left-hand side. Given such a straightforward derivation, I'm led to suspect that the identity exists *somewhere* in the literature; finding trig relations used to be a bigger deal than it is today. Of course, this does not diminish your own accomplishment in deriving it.

Comment: Hi @Blue! As the great geometer Ivan Zelich says: "it is much easier to find a direct derivation to a result that is already known." But of course, I do not rule out the possibility that you point out.

Comment: I have no idea if this identity is well known. My guess is that it has been seen somewhere. I can provide a proof of the identity, but I am not sure that that is what you are looking for. If you have a proof and are simply looking for the identity in print, it would provide wonderful [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) to include the proof.

Comment: If you don't have a proof, it would be nice to know where you found this identity. In any case, as it stands, this is a [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854), and may be closed by the community.

Comment: @robjohn I have derived this identity myself and have my own (perhaps not the simplest) proof. In the post I have explicitly asked my question. What I am interested in knowing is if this generalization of the Law of Tangents is known. But I need references, I can't put suspicions about imaginary books in an article.

Comment: I can improve the question later. I cannot now.

Comment: When you have improved the question, I will post my solution (if significantly different). In any case, you can cite this question or any answers, if no other source is found for this identity. BibTeX and amsrefs citations can be generated using the "Cite" link (between the post and comments).

Comment: @robjohn I won't be on a PC until the weekend, but essentially what I did was rewrite the tangents in terms of sines and cosines and substitute the half angle formulas . In this link (https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2022/01/generalization-of-mollweides-formulas.html) you can see an example of how I use the half angle formulas to generalize Mollweide's (rather Newton's) formula. In metric relations, it seems that the centrality of half-angle formulas has gone unnoticed by generations of geometers through time.

Comment: @robjohn Please, if you know any reference of that generalization of Mollweide's formula let me know.

Comment: I don't have any reference for Mollweide's Formula. I will work on a proof along a similar approach to my answer for this question, but I am still waiting for improvements.  If I post and there is not more context, I fear that close votes will follow soon.

Comment: @robjohn Sorry, my PC crashed. Please feel free to edit the question however you see fit. Later I'll add my proof.

Comment: @robjohn I have improved the question.

Comment: (+1) I have undeleted my answer.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419185/a-generalization-of-the-law-of-tangents

Answer (score 3):

**The Usual Law of Tangents**

Applying [the formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) for the Sum of Sines and the Sum of Cosines, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(A)+\sin(B)}{\cos(A)+\cos(B)}
&=\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}2\right)}{2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}2\right)}\\[6pt]
&=\tan\left(\tfrac{A+B}2\right)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Substituting $B\mapsto-B$ in $(1)$ and then dividing by $(1)$ gives
$$
\frac{\sin(A)-\sin(B)}{\sin(A)+\sin(B)}=\frac{\tan\left(\frac{A-B}2\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)}\tag2
$$
If we let $a$ and $b$ be the sides opposite angles $A$ and $B$ respectively, the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) leads to
$$
\frac{a-b}{a+b}=\frac{\sin(A)-\sin(B)}{\sin(A)+\sin(B)}\tag3
$$

Equating $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get the [Law of Tangents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents)
$$
\frac{a-b}{a+b}=\frac{\tan\left(\frac{A-B}2\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)}\tag4
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the sides of a triangle opposite angles $A$ and $B$ respectively.

---

**Inscribed Generalization**

[image]

The [power of the point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) $S$ is equal to both
$\overline{SA}\,\overline{SD}=\overline{SB}\,\overline{SC}$; therefore,
$$
\frac{\overline{SA}}{\overline{SB}}=\frac{\overline{SC}}{\overline{SD}}\tag5
$$
and since $\angle ASB=\angle CSD$, [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Determining_congruence) says that
$$
\triangle ASB\simeq\triangle CSD\tag6
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\overline{SA}}{\overline{SC}}=\frac{\overline{SB}}{\overline{SD}}=\frac ac\tag7
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\begin{align}
b&=\overline{SB}-\overline{SC}=\overline{SB}-\overline{SA}\frac ca\tag{8a}\\[6pt]
d&=\overline{SA}-\overline{SD}=\overline{SA}-\overline{SB}\frac ca\tag{8b}
\end{align}
$$
From $(8)$, we can solve
$$
\begin{align}
\overline{SA}&=a\frac{ad+bc}{a^2-c^2}\tag{9a}\\[3pt]
\overline{SB}&=a\frac{ab+cd}{a^2-c^2}\tag{9b}
\end{align}
$$
Now we are ready to apply the usual Law of Tangents from $(4)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\right)}
&=\frac{\overline{SB}-\overline{SA}}{\overline{SB}+\overline{SA}}\tag{10a}\\
&=\frac{(ab+cd)-(ad+bc)}{(ab+cd)+(ad+bc)}\tag{10b}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a+c)(b+d)}\tag{10c}
\end{align}
$$